# Creating and appending to an array, mapfile vs arr+=(input) same thing or am I missing something?

Tags: bash-array

Is there a case where `mapfile` has benefits over `arr+=(input)`?

### Simple examples

#### mapfile array name, arr:

```bash
mkdir {1,2,3}

mapfile -t arr < <(ls)

declare -p arr
```

#### output:

```bash
declare -a arr=([0])="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
```

Edit:

changed title for below; the body had `y` as the array name, but the title had `arr` as the name, which this could lead to confusion.

### y+=(input)

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

y+=($(ls))

declare -p y
```

#### output:

```bash
declare -a y=([0])="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
```

---

An advantage to `mapfile` is you don't have to worry about word splitting I think.

For the other way you can avoid word splitting by setting `IFS=$'\n'` although for this example it's nothing to worry about.

The second example just seems easier to write, anything I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not the same thing at all, even after `IFS=$'\n'`.

In bash specifically (though that syntax was borrowed from zsh¹):

```
arr=( $(cmd) )
```

(`arr+=( $(cmd) )` would be used to *append* elements to the array; so would be compared with `keys=( -1 "${!arr[@]}" ); readarray -tO "$(( ${keys[@]: -1} + 1))" arr < <(cmd)`²).

Does:

1. Run `cmd` in a subshell with its stdout open on the writing end a pipe.
2. Simultaneously, the parent shell process reads from the other end of the pipe and:

   - removes the NUL characters and trailing newline characters
   - splits the resulting string based on the contents of the `$IFS` special variable. For those characters in `$IFS` that are whitespace characters such as newline, the behaviour is more complex in that:

     - leading and trailing ones are removed (in the case of newline, they've been removed by command substitution already as seen above)
     - sequences of one or more are treated as *one* separator. As an example, the output of `printf '\n\n\na\n\n\nb\n\n\n'` is split into two elements only: `a` and `b`.
   - each of these words is then subject to filename generation aka globbing, whose behaviour is affected by a number of options including `noglob`, `nullglob`, `failglob`, `extglob`, `globasciiranges`, `glabstar`, `nocaseglob`. That applies to those words that contain characters such as `*`, `?`, `[`, and with some bash versions `\`, and more if `extglob` is enabled.
3. Then the resulting words are assigned as elements to the `$arr` array.

Example:

```
bash-5.1$ touch x '\x' '?x' aX $'foo\n\n\n\n*'
bash-5.1$ IFS=$'\n'
bash-5.1$ ls | cat
aX
foo



*
?x
\x
x
bash-5.1$ arr=( $(ls) )
bash-5.1$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="aX" [1]="foo" [2]="aX" [3]=$'foo\n\n\n\n*' [4]="?x" [5]="\\x" [6]="x" [7]="?x" [8]="\\x" [9]="\\x" [10]="x")
```

As you can see, the `$'foo\n\n\n\n*'` file was split into `foo` and `*` and `*` was expanded to the list of files in the current working directory which explains why we get both `foo` and `$'foo\n\n\n\n*'`, same for `?x` which explains why we get `\x` (shown as `"\\x"`) 3 times as there's the `\x` line in the output of `ls` and it's matched by both `*` and `?x`.

With bash 5.0, we get:

```
bash-5.0$ arr=( $(ls) )
bash-5.0$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="aX" [1]="foo" [2]="aX" [3]=$'foo\n\n\n\n*' [4]="?x" [5]="\\x" [6]="x" [7]="?x" [8]="\\x" [9]="x" [10]="x")
```

With `\x` only twice but `x` three times as in that version, backslash was a globbing operator even when not followed by a globbing operator so `\x` as a glob matches `x`.

After `shopt nocaseglob`, we get:

```
bash-5.1$ shopt -s nocaseglob
bash-5.1$ arr=( $(ls) )
bash-5.1$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="aX" [1]="foo" [2]="aX" [3]=$'foo\n\n\n\n*' [4]="?x" [5]="\\x" [6]="x" [7]="aX" [8]="?x" [9]="\\x" [10]="\\x" [11]="x")
```

With `aX` shown 3 times as it matches `?x` as well.

After `shopt -s failglob`:

```
bash-5.0$ shopt -s failglob
bash-5.0$ arr=( $(printf '\\z\n') )
bash: no match: \z
bash-5.0$ arr=( $(printf 'WTF\n?') )
bash: no match: WTF?
```

And `arr=( $(echo '/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*') )`

Runs out of memory after having made your system unusable for several minutes.

So, to sum up, `IFS=$'\n'; arr=( $(cmd) )` doesn't store the lines of the output of `cmd` in the array, but the filenames resulting from the expansion of the non-empty lines of the output of `cmd` which are treated as glob patterns.

---

With `mapfile` or its less misleading `readarray` alias:

```
readarray -t arr < <(cmd)
```

1. as above runs `cmd` in a subshell with its stdout open on the writing end of a pipe.
2. the `<(...)` is expanded to something like `/dev/fd/63` or `/proc/self/fd/63` where `63` is a file descriptor of the parent shell open on the reading end of that pipe.
3. with the `<` redirection short for `0<`, that /dev/fd/63 is opened for reading on fd 0, which means the stdin of `readarray` will also be the reading end of that pipe.
4. `readarray` reads each line from that pipe (simultaneously from `cmd` writing to it), discards the line delimiter (`-t`), and stores it (up to the first NUL if it contains any, at least in current versions of bash) in a new element of the `$arr`.

So in the end `$arr`, assuming `cmd` outputs no NUL will contain the contents of each line of the output of `cmd`, regardless of whether they're empty or not of whether they contain glob characters or not.

With the example above:

```
bash-5.1$ readarray -t arr < <(ls)
bash-5.1$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="aX" [1]="foo" [2]="" [3]="" [4]="" [5]="*" [6]="?x" [7]="\\x" [8]="x")
```

That's consistent with what we saw in the output of `ls | cat` earlier, but that's still wrong if the intention was to get the list of files in the current working directory. The output of `ls` cannot be post-processed unless you use some extensions of the GNU implementation of `ls` such as `--quoting-style=shell-always` or the `--zero` of recent versions (9.0 or above):

```
bash-5.2$ readarray -td '' arr < <(ls --zero)
bash-5.2$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="aX" [1]=$'foo\n\n\n\n*' [2]="?x" [3]="\\x" [4]="x")
```

This time, `readarray` stores the contents of the NUL-`d`elimited records into `$arr`. `IFS=$'\0'` can't be used in `bash` as `bash` can't store NULs in its variables.

Or:

```
bash-5.1$ eval "arr=( $(ls --quoting-style=shell-always) )"
bash-5.1$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="aX" [1]=$'foo\n\n\n\n*' [2]="?x" [3]="\\x" [4]="x")
```

In any case, the correct way to get the list of files in the current working directory into an array would be with:

```
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( * )
```

You'd only resort to `ls --zero` if you wanted for instance the list to be sorted by size or modification time which bash globs (contrary to zsh's) cannot do.

As in:

| zsh | recent GNU bash + GNU coreutils |
| --- | --- |
| `new_to_old=( *.txt(Nom) )` | `readarray -td '' new_to_old < <(ls -td --zero -- *.txt)` |
| `four_largest=( *.txt(NOL[1,4]) )` | `readarray -td '' four_largest < <(ls -tdrS --zero -- *.txt | head -zn4)` |

Another difference between `a=($(cmd))` and `readarray < <(cmd)` is the exit status which in the former is that of `cmd` and in the latter that of `readarray`. With recent versions of `bash`, you can get the exist status of `cmd` in the latter with `wait "$!"; cmd_status=$?`.

---

<sup>¹ the `arr=( ... )` syntax comes from zsh (bash didn't have arrays until 2.0 in 1996), but note that in zsh, command substitution, while it's also stripping trailing newlines and subject to `$IFS`-stripping, does not discard NULs (NUL is even in the default value of `$IFS` there) and is not subject to globbing like in other Bourne-like shells, contributing to making it a safer shell in general.</sup>

<sup>² `readarray` aka `mapfile` doesn't have an append mode, but in recent versions you can tell it the index of the first element where to start storing the elements with `-O` as shown here. To find out the index of the last element in bash (where arrays are sparse like in ksh!), it's awfully difficult. Here to append the lines of the output of `cmd` to `$arr`, instead of that very convoluted code, you might as well read those lines into a temporary array with `readarray -r tmp < <(cmd)` and append the elements to `$arr` with `arr+=( "${tmp[@]}" )`. Also note that if the `arr` variable was declared as scalar or assoc, the behaviour will vary between those approaches.</sup>

Comment: `arr+=(cmd)`  creates and appends the array as does `mapfile -t arr < <<(cmd)` from what I got mapfile is better to use in some cases as you don't have to set things, is that right? I notice you hate the word mapfile :), would mapArray be better? Point noted on not using ls, I'll do `*.mp4` or just `*` next time.

Comment: @Nickotine, it doesn't *map*, it only *reads*, `readarray` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Nikotine, note that zsh had `$mapfile[some/file]` to truely *map* a file long before bash added its `mapfile` builtin which doesn't map and works on streams, not files specifically (can be used on sockets or pipes just the same for instance)

Comment: I appreciate that zsh is better, but is the bash syntax not a bit easier? The zsh syntax is easy as well though. Well now I understand your frustration with mapfile since it doesn't map. Can you please answer my question on the first comment so I know I understand properly? On one of the questions I thought I understood you then you pointed out that I didn't and gave me an example which made me get it.

Comment: I think you would've called me out if my understanding was incorrect. Much appreciated as always.

Comment: There's no `<<(...)` operator. `mapfile -t arr < <(cmd)` *replaces* the contents of the array with the lines of cmd's output, so it's closer to `arr=( $(cmd) )`.

Comment: It's the other way round, zsh syntax is a lot easier. Most people write zsh syntax when they think they write  bash syntax. For instance `rm -- $file` is zsh syntax, in bash you need `rm -- "$file"`. Compare zsh's `rm -- $files` with `bash`'s `rm -- "${files[@]}"`, etc.

Comment: sorry that operator was a typo

Comment: it's just I see some of your zsh stuff and I can write a much simpler and readable bash version. However I'll jump on zsh (I'm on mac) if you can convince me, it just seems a bit esoteric and while I can use pure bash stuff I usually treat bash like a programming language which makes it easy to read.

Comment: Well, show me an example of a simpler bash version of some of my zsh stuff

Comment: I take it back, I just seen your bash vs zsh table and the zsh syntax is 1000 times better. One question is bash like a nerfed version of zsh, I think you have convinced me.